# npm table won't populate cli command line table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, terminal

I was trying to use npm table to create a table in command line, however it does not work, let me show you my code and explain it.

```
const {table} = require('table');

let data;
let output;

data = [['id','product','name']];

output = table(data);
console.log(output);

connection.connect(e => e 
         ?     () => {throw e 
                           ? console.log(e) 
                           : false
                      } 
         :    connection.query("SELECT item_id,product_name,price FROM products",
             (e, r) => e 
                      ? false 
                      : (console.log(`${JSON.stringify(r,null,'\t')}`),
                        ()=>{for(let i=0;i<r.length;i++){data.push(Object.values(r[i]))}},
                        output=table(data),
                        console.log(output)
                        )
                              )
                   )
```

So basically we are getting information from the DB as an array of objects, then I turn the objects into arrays of props and trying to push them into the data array for the table, however, when I'm console.logging it, only top three rows show...

Comment: Please format your code, don't use inline constructions, it's impossible to read. I don't see where you call your arrow function with `for` loop. You have `id','product','name'` in table, but `item_id,product_name,price` in sql

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line:
 `()=>{for(let i=0;i<r.length;i++){data.push(Object.values(r[i]))}}`. You are defining a function that updates `data` with the DB values, but you never call this function.
Adding `()` at the end of this line to call this function would probably fix the issue
`()=>{for(let i=0;i<r.length;i++){data.push(Object.values(r[i]))}}()`,
but personally I would simplify this logic.